# Swing Timer Not Working (Java)

Tags: java, swing, timer, jframe, jpanel

For some reason even though I am using the exact code example from oracle's website for the Swing Timer it is not waiting for 1 second. It just skips to the JOptionPane that says "Your score was etc etc".

Here is my source code for a school project. Why is this not working and not waiting for 1 second before running the rest of the code?

```
//Check to see if user has enetered anything
if(!answered)
{
    int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
    ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            //...Perform a task...
        }
    };
    new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
    afk = true;
    incorrect += 1;
    answered = true; //This breakes it out of the loop
}
```

Comment: You've posted a lot of code, much of it unrelated to your problem, which simply is that the timer is not working. I urge you to trim down your code to the smallest compilable and runnable program that demonstrates your problem, an [mcve](http://sscce.org). This will help *you* in that isolating the problem often helps you to see it and solve it, and it helps *us* in that if you don't fix it with this exercise, we will have code that is much easier to understand test and correct.

Comment: Your code after your timer call is not and should not be delayed. What is delayed is only that which is in the Timer's ActionListener.

Comment: Ok I did but you still did not clarify at all why my code is not working.

Comment: You did nothing of the sort -- please re-read the comment as you should only post compilable and runnable code -- a small self-contained program that demonstrates your problem and nothing else.

Comment: Again, it seems that you have an invalid assumption here. You seem to be thinking that by starting a Timer, all code calls after the Timer will be delayed until the Timer finishes, and that simply is not true. The Timer instead will only call the code within its ActionListener repeatedly (if desired) and after a certain delay.

Comment: Also on a side note, look into use of a CardLayout to help you swap JPanels which is usually much simpler and cleaner than adding and removing components. Also I thought I saw a `null` layout snuck in there somewhere -- avoid use of these if humanly possible since they lead to the production of inflexible ugly GUI's that are wickedly difficult to update or enhance.

Answer (score 8):

A timer is used to run a callback after a specific amount of time. If you simply want to delay, you can either move the code to be run after the delay *into* the `taskPerformer` action listener.

`Thread.sleep(1000)` is not ideal here, because it will cause the UI to completely freeze as you will make the UI thread sleep.